# Error location HDF5 libraries, earlier it was locating them just fine, i recently installed gcc7.2 environment? PS. error message and configure

Tags: software-installation, python, cmake

Error:

```
-- Setting option BUILD_SHARED_LIBS: ON
-- Setting option ENABLE_OPENMP: ON
-- Setting option ENABLE_AUTO_BLAS: ON
-- Setting option ENABLE_AUTO_LAPACK: ON
-- Setting option ENABLE_PLUGIN_TESTING: OFF
-- Setting option ENABLE_XHOST: ON
-- Performing Test CMAKE_C_FLAGS [-xHost] - Success, Appending
-- Performing Test CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS [-xHost] - Success, Appending
-- Performing Test CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS [-xHost] - Success, Appending
-- Setting option ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE: OFF
-- Setting option ENABLE_BOUNDS_CHECK: OFF
-- Setting option ENABLE_ASAN: OFF
-- Setting option ENABLE_TSAN: OFF
-- Setting option ENABLE_UBSAN: OFF
-- Setting option ENABLE_MSAN: OFF
-- Setting option MAX_AM_ERI: 6
-- Setting option CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: Release
-- Setting option FC_SYMBOL: 2
-- Setting option BUILD_FPIC: ON
-- Setting option CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR: lib
-- Setting option PYMOD_INSTALL_LIBDIR: /
-- Setting option ENABLE_GENERIC: OFF
-- Setting option CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE: LAZY
-- Setting option psi4_CXX_STANDARD: 11
-- Setting option SIMINT_VECTOR: avx
-- Psi4 install: /home/rakesh/codes/Psi4
-- Found Python 3.6: /opt/intel/intelpython3/bin/python3.6 (found version 3.6.3)
-- Found LAPACK MKL: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a;...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES) (found version "1.10.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindHDF5.cmake:398 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  external/common/hdf5/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

configure:

```
cmake -H. -Bpsi4comp \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/rakesh/codes/Psi4/ \
        -DMAX_AM_ERI=6 \
        -DHDF5_LIBRARIES="/opt/intel/intelpython3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.1-intel_0/lib/libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.100.1.0" \
        -DHDF5_EXECUTABLE="/opt/intel/intelpython/bin/h5c++"\
        -DENABLE_gdma=ON \
        -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icc \
        -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-gnu-prefix=/opt/intel/intelpython3/envs/gcc72/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-" \
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpc \
        -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-gnu-prefix=/opt/intel/intelpython3/envs/gcc72/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-" \
        -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=ifort \
        -DCMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS="-gnu-prefix=/opt/intel/intelpython3/envs/gcc72/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-" \
        -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE="/opt/intel/intelpython3/bin/python3.6" \
        -DPYTHON_LIBRARY="/opt/intel/intelpython3/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0" \
        -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR="/opt/intel/intelpython3/include" \
        -DBLAS_TYPE=MKL \
        -DLAPACK_TYPE=MKL \
        -DLAPACK_LIBRARIES="/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a;/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so" \
        -DLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.163/linux/mkl/include \
        -DHDF5_LIBRARIES="/opt/intel/intelpython3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.1-intel_0/lib/libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.100.1.0" \
        -DHDF5_EXECUTABLE="/opt/intel/intelpython/bin/h5c++" \
~
```

Requested output of `apt-cache policy libhdf4-dev libhdf5-dev`:

```
libhdf4-dev: 
Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 4.2.10-3.2 
Version table: 
    4.2.10-3.2 500
    500 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages 

libhdf5-dev: 
Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1 
Version table: 
    1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1 500
    500 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What is you Ubuntu version? Do you have installed `libhdf4-dev` and `libhdf5-dev` packages?

Comment: @N0rbert Ubuntu version is probably the latest, installed it just a month back or so (16.4 or so), sorry I'm away from my laptop. How do I check if these packages are installed. Please not that Earlier it used to find hdf5 easilu, it also detects the installed version but doesn't find the libraries.

Comment: @N0rbert libhdf4-dev: Installed: (none) Candidate: 4.2.10-3.2 Version table: 4.2.10-3.2 500 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages libhdf5-dev: Installed: (none) Candidate: 1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1 Version table: 1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1 500 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: appended
;echo $(apt-cache policy libhdf4-dev libhdf5-dev)

Comment: Also here is the Ubuntu version details:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release: 16.04

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. :) 
"Install :(none)" means it was not installed, is ti?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed necessary HDF-related development packages

```
apt-cache policy libhdf4-dev libhdf5-dev
```

and if they are not installed, install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf4-dev libhdf5-dev
```